# "TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type" error with my code

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
raw = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ozanerturk/covid19-turkey-api/master/dataset/timeline.json')
raw_json= raw.json()
df = pd.DataFrame.transpose('raw_json')
```

When i am running this code, i get this error:

```
   1774         """Transpose index and columns"""
   1775         nv.validate_transpose(args, dict())
-> 1776         return super(DataFrame, self).transpose(1, 0, **kwargs)
   1777 
   1778     T = property(transpose)

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Before i add the .transpose, everything was working fine.

Comment: You're passing string `"raw_json"` to transpose, which it cannot do. Remove the quotes to pass the *variable* `raw_json` i.e., the dataframe itself.

Comment: @MustafaAydın `raw_json` is not a dataframe. It will almost certainly fail as well. Probably, the OP wants `pd.DataFrame(raw_json).transpose()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the correction, didn't look close enough.